# Spring: Injecting Properties using @Value and setting a default

Tags: spring, groovy

So, I'm trying to set a default properties file for dbProperties. But it doesn't seem to work.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? Any help would be appreciated.

This is what I have in my Application.xml file:

```
<util:properties id="dbProps" location="classpath:dbConf.properties" />
<util:properties id="defaultDbProps" location="classpath:dbConf.properties" />

@Configuration
class DBConfig {
   @Value('#{dbProps:#{defaultDbProps}}')
   private Properties dbProperties
}
```

My end goal is to point dbProperties to defaultDbProps if dbProps is not provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before all: `defaultDbProps` location is the same of `dbProps` one.

You are accessing properties value in the wrong way (with spEL); use `${}` tag in this manner `@Value('${my.property}')`, but to have `${}` available you need a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`:

```
<bean id="placeholderConfig" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="propertiesArray">
    <list>
      <ref bean="defaultDbProps"/>
      <ref bean="dbProps"/>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

with this bean defaultDbProps are loaded first, then dbProps overrides properties with the same name